# Can't analyze the roots of $3x^4 + 6x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 3$

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, roots

I have to analyze the roots of $3x^4 + 6x^3 + x^2 + 6x + 3$ and answer how many roots are real. There is a way to solve this by factorization but I want to solve it by differentiation. So I have tried this,

$$
  f(x) = 3x^4 + 6x^3 + x^2 + 6x + 3
$$

$$
  f'(x) = 12x^3 + 18x^2 + 2x + 6
$$

$$
  f''(x) = 36x^2 + 36x + 2
$$

From $f''(x)=0$, we can say that $f(x)$ has inflection points at two points as the determinant of $f''(x)$ is greater than zero. But the roots seem to be irrational, $\frac{-3 + \sqrt{7}}{6}$ and $\frac{-3 - \sqrt{7}}{6}$. Trying to substitute these values in $f'(x)$ will require a bit of hairy calculation. So I approximated the roots to be $0$ and $-1$ and got the right answer to be two.
But I want to know if I'm doing it right and will this method work for any function.
Any other efficient solution will be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: See [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for counting real roots. [Desargues' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) tells you that there are no positive roots.

Comment: @plop Thank you for Descartes rule, I didn't completely understand Sturm's theorem but I'll try to do some problems on it to understand. Do you think my initial method of solving by derivatives works? I am trying to learn the specifics of graphs and derivatives, so your answer helps.